# dictionnary with hexadecimal value

Tags: tcl

I would like to set a dict like this :

```
set d [dict create]
dict set d color [list #d87c7c #919e8b]
```

But I don't understand why the first value of my color has curly braces :

```
dict get $d color
> {#d87c7c} #919e8b
```

How to get the result of `dict get $d color`  without the curly braces ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you're seeing the braces getting added to disambiguate the leading `#` from ever being able to be mistaken for a comment. For whatever the reason, it can be stripped by explicitly converting the list to a single string, which stops the printing code from escaping particular elements:

```
% set d [dict create]
% dict set d color [list #d87c7c #919e8b]
color {{#d87c7c} #919e8b}
% dict get $d color
{#d87c7c} #919e8b
% join [dict get $d color]
#d87c7c #919e8b
```

Comment: Braces are added to the first word of a list if it begins with a `#` so that we can guarantee that lists are well-formed (substitution-free) commands, a _supremely_ desirable property. Using `lindex` to retrieve the first element will show that the logical value doesn't have braces; it's just part of the list formatting.